# Предпросмотр "офисных" документов в приложении

Tags: pdf, любой-язык, doc, open-office, rtf

В данный момент занимаюсь разработкой одного десктопного приложения(с графическим интерфейсом). В нем нужно реализовать "предпросмотр" документов(форматы doc,docx,pdf,rtf,xml и проч).
Редактирование не нужно, только возможность "полистать" документ.

Каким ***наиболее простым*** способом, можно реализовать этот функционал?

Требуется наиболее простое решение, потому что предпросмотр документов это малая часть  того что необходимо выполнить.
Кучу вариантов уже испробовал, перерыл OpenOffice API, но решение не нашел.

Язык программирования, на котором будет подсказано решение - не важен.

Comment: Интерфейс uno пробовали? У меня где-то был пример как открыть в режиме readonly, или это не подходит?

Comment: В этом случае файл откроется со всем интерфейсом OpenOffice? Или будет возможность встроить только сам открывшийся документ в интерфейс приложения?

Comment: теоретически вы можете использоватся стандартным диалогом системы который используется для предпросмотра документов при печати. 

p.s. указали бы какие средства исопльзуете (хотя бы язык) вам бы точнее подсказали

Answer (score 1):

Я писал [модуль на питоне](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/genres/oo.py?root=genres&view=markup) через python-uno.

Делал давно, не факт что сегодня работает.
В linux можно встраивать через xembed.
Меню, тулбары вроде убираемы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перед выполнением функции предпросмотра реализовать такую "связку": документ -> конвертация в HTML (PDF, XML с помощью соответствующих тегов, плагинов) -> открытие в окне своей программы локальной HTML-страницы (способов встроить веб-броузер в свою программу существует множество).

**Еще мысль:** есть ф-я `ShellExecute`. Если не требуется открывать файл для редактирования, то предварительно изменяйте атрибуты файлов на "только чтение".

Comment: Да,была примерно такая же мысль. Но хотелось бы найти более "красивое" решение. В любом случае, спасибо за идею!